# Wi-Fi says connected, but my internet does not work until I turn it on and off

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi

I just got my first macbook, an used early 2014 14-inch macbook air, with Mac OS Mojave. And everything works fine but when im connected to the wifi, after like about 20-30 minutes it just stops working. and it always starts working back up when I turn wifi on and off, or when I disconnect off the network, and connect back up.
It says I am still connected to the network, but there is no internet.
I already tried doing a wireless diagnosis and tried contacting apple support multiple times.

UPDATE:

```
Unused argument: –
Too many arguments to 'show' verb
usage: log show [options] <archive>
   or: log show [options]

description:
    Show the contents of the system log datastore or a log archive.
    Output contains only default level messages unless --info and/or
    --debug are specified.

options:
    --[no-]backtrace              Control whether backtraces are shown
    --[no-]debug                  Control whether "Debug" events are shown
    --[no-]info                   Control whether "Info" events are shown
    --[no-]loss                   Control whether message loss events are shown
    --[no-]signpost               Control whether signposts are shown
    --color <mode>                Control color output (valid: auto, always, none)
    --end <date>                  Display events up to the given end date
    --last <num>[m|h|d]           Display recent events up to the given limit
    --predicate <predicate>       Filter events using the given predicate
    --source                      Annotate output with source file and line-number
    --start <date>                Display events from the given start date
    --style <style>               Output format (valid: syslog, json, compact)
    --timezone local | <tz>       Use the given timezone when displaying event timestamps
    --mach-continuous-time        Print mach continuous time timestamps rather than walltime

valid time formats:
    'Y-M-D H:m:s+zzzz', 'Y-M-D H:m:s', 'Y-M-D', '@unixtime'

predicate usage:
    Filter predicates follow the NSPredicate format described at:
    https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/AdditionalChapters/Introduction.html

    For predicate field/type details, see `log help predicates`.
```

This is what showed up after the last step I was told.

[image]

Please help me out if somebody knows what is going on

Comment: Does it happen with all Wi-Fi hotspots?

Comment: there are 2 connections. One is from your mac to the router. The other is from the router to your internet provider. WiFi connected only means you are connected to your router, but it does not mean you actually have internet.

Comment: It has happened with both networks I have at home. It did not happen with my other laptop, nor does it happen with my roomates macbook pro

Comment: Great, thank you for providing more info. The information all looks good. Lets also check if some setting on your Mac does that. Just to clarify loosing Internet happens while you are actively using your Mac.

Comment: @Buscar웃 Thank you, so is anything wrong with my software or hardware? Because it happened twice yesterday, but it hasnt happened all day today the connection problem

Comment: What's your lease time?  Issue the command `ipconfig getpacket en0 | grep lease_time`  You will get a hex value so it will have to be converted to get the number of seconds.  But post it and we can go from there.

Comment: ipconfig getpacket en0 | grep lease_time
lease_time (uint32): 0x3f480

Comment: Pretty common issue. It has happened on every Mac I've worked with over the last few years. I've never been able to find any real cause.  Happens on wired, wifi, with or without VPN, and it's happened on completely clean installs dating back to at least Mavericks (for me, at least).  Same fix every time - stop and start networking and it'll start working again.

Comment: What is the output you show from? The exact command please. It is probably not what was asked for as it shows a bad argument?

Answer (score 1):

The Terminal command to show WiFi disconnects for last 24 hours is:

```
log show --predicate '(processImagePath contains "kernel") && (eventMessage contains "AirPort: Link Down")' --style syslog --last 1d
```

and the output looks like this

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84569/discussion-on-answer-by-buscar-wi-fi-says-connected-but-my-internet-does-not-w).